# Write a Unit test on Static Void method which changes the properties of aTable in the Database in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I've been trying to figure out how we actually write the Unit tests on the void method that Just updates some properties of a particular table  in the Database.

The Idea was that  we  could set it up in such a way that
we create a Mock DB then run the Method saving to the Mock DB and check the results by querying the Mocked DB to see if the results that are saved were correct.
Here is the blue Method which I wanted to write a Unit testcase.

```
    public static class Staff
    {
        private static readonly IUnityContainer Unity = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
        public static void RecalculateCompliance(long staffID, long accountID, long userID, Guid transactionID, long staffComplianceID = 0, string result = null, DateTime? effectiveDate = null, DateTime? throughDate = null)
        {
            
            using (var entities = Unity.Resolve<IDBContext>())
            {
                entities.TransactionID = transactionID;
                var user = entities.Users.// gets some data


// does some changes to the props...

entities.SaveChanges();
```

**NOTE**: This method is not in any Repository! it just takes a set of input values and updates

And the Table which it changes the properties is  
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYRJ.png)

[here is what I did so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNNOD.png) 
But It doesn't make any sense to me how to proceed.

Any suggestion on How to proceed would really help me.
Using the EF Core. Please bear with me here I never written a single test case in C# till now. Hoping this would be nice start for me.

Comment: You should (must) inject `IVincentContext` into that method. Or create non-static class with non-static method and inject to the constructor.

Comment: DI-container must be used only in [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)